# Как реализовать видеоредактор для мобильных устройств

Tags: php, c#, unity3d

Коротко о сути приложения:

1. Пользователь может снимать видео и редактировать его( мелкие эффекты
   типо переходы, звук дорожка, затемнение и т.п)
2. Видео пользователя может храниться на облаке.

Хотелось бы узнать какие библиотеки или быть может готовые sdk можно использовать. Быть может есть ресурсы где есть информация об этом.

Php [библиотеку](https://github.com/nixsolutions/yandex-php-library/wiki/Yandex-Disk) для работы к примеру с яндекс диском я нашел

Также слышал немного о [Bass Audio](http://www.un4seen.com/) для аудио и [VideoLab](http://www.mitov.com/html/products.html) для видео.

В целом это будет некий видеоредактор с возможностью хранения файлов на облаке на мобильные устройства.
Средой разработки использую unity( смена среды разработки не составит особого труда)

Answer (score 1):

Углубляйтесь в сторону WebRTC, HTML5, JQuery.
Гуглите, качайте библиотеки и пробуйте.
http://videojs.com/

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Comment: Peer-to-peer передача и инструменты для сборки веб-приложений для редактирования видео? Где связь?